# How to scrape large number of images from google images?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I used a code snippet I found for scraping images from Google. It works perfectly when the number of images to be scraped is around 100 or lower. I need to scrape about 1000 for each query that I input into the program. When I use the  following code for small images, it works fine :

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'webdriver/chromedriver'

def fetch_image_urls(query:str, max_links_to_fetch:int, wd:webdriver, sleep_between_interactions:int=1):
    def scroll_to_end(wd):
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)    
    
    # build the google query
    search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img"

    # load the page
    wd.get(search_url.format(q=query))

    image_urls = set()
    image_count = 0
    results_start = 0
    while image_count < max_links_to_fetch:
        scroll_to_end(wd)

        # get all image thumbnail results
        thumbnail_results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.Q4LuWd")
        number_results = len(thumbnail_results)
        
        print(f"Found: {number_results} search results. Extracting links from {results_start}:{number_results}")
        
        for img in thumbnail_results[results_start:number_results]:
            # try to click every thumbnail such that we can get the real image behind it
            try:
                img.click()
                time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
            except Exception:
                continue

            # extract image urls    
            actual_images = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.n3VNCb')
            for actual_image in actual_images:
                if actual_image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in actual_image.get_attribute('src'):
                    image_urls.add(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))

            image_count = len(image_urls)

            if len(image_urls) >= max_links_to_fetch:
                print(f"Found: {len(image_urls)} image links, done!")
                break
        else:
            print("Found:", len(image_urls), "image links, looking for more ...")
            time.sleep(30)
            return
            load_more_button = wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")
            if load_more_button:
                wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('.mye4qd').click();")

        # move the result startpoint further down
        results_start = len(thumbnail_results)

    return image_urls

def persist_image(folder_path:str,file_name:str,url:str):
    try:
        image_content = requests.get(url).content

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not download {url} - {e}")

    try:
        image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
        image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
        folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file_name)
        if os.path.exists(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + '.jpg')
        else:
            os.mkdir(folder_path)
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + '.jpg')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
        print(f"SUCCESS - saved {url} - as {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not save {url} - {e}")
```

Which I later call in the code like:

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=op, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
queries = tags 
for query in queries:
    wd.get('https://google.com')
    search_box = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input.gLFyf')
    search_box.send_keys(query)
    links = fetch_image_urls(query,1000,wd)
    images_path = 'scraped_photos_test'
    for i in links:
        persist_image(images_path,query,i)
wd.quit()
```

But when I use it for say `1000` images I get the following error:

```
Found: 100 search results. Extracting links from 0:100
Found: 171 image links, looking for more ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-4f7bad1467e9> in <module>()
      9     links = fetch_image_urls(query,1000,wd)
     10     images_path = 'scraped_photos_test'
---> 11     for i in links:
     12         persist_image(images_path,query,i)
     13 wd.quit()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I tried going over the snippet to see why I was getting the error, but I can't understand why it would return null even when it shows that `171 image links` are found. Also, there is no upper limit set in the code and it's specified only in the function call so I can't comprehend why is it not scraping 1000 images with this code.

How do I change the code to be able to scrape 1000 images?

Comment: It can be so that Google just has some protections from bulk requests like yours. Try maybe some debugging proxy like Fiddler or OWASP-ZAP, see what the error would be in the request, and also try to reissue failed request after a minute or two to see whether it completes successfully.

Comment: Seems like it hit this:  time.sleep(30)  return   (don't know python, but the code after it doesn't seem like it would run and it would return null?)